# Excel xlsm add data form Sheets to Master sheet

Tags: excel, vba, merge, xlsm

I have a master sheet (Master) containing various data (columns and rows) and a few separate sheets (SheetA, SheetB, etc) with the same columns. I want to add rows in the SheetA, SheetB, etc. and following the new rows should be automatically added to the master sheet (Master).

I tried using Macros or an Excel function but couldn't manage to do it. I hope someone can help me.
Probably this question is common, but I wasn't able to find a a right answer for my problem.

The most promising solution that I could find was the following

```
Sub Combine()
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xRg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets.Add Sheets(1)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Combined"
   For I = 2 To Sheets.Count
        Set xRg = Sheets(1).UsedRange
        If I > 2 Then
            Set xRg = Sheets(1).Cells(xRg.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
        End If
        Sheets(I).Activate
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy xRg
    Next
End Sub
```

Sadly my knowledge is pretty limited and therefore I don't know how to change the code in order to merge only one Sheet (SheetA) to the Matsersheet (Master) without creating a new one

Thanks in advance to who can help me.

Comment: I tried some different ones that I found here on stackoverflow The most promising I have updated in the question. Thanks for the info

Comment: Welcome to SO. Something you should note: this isn't a free coding service. It's purpose is for coders to help other coders (even if the asker is a complete novice). That means you need to make an attempt, then show your work and seek help with specific issues. What you've done here however, amounts to simply asking "can someone write some free code for me?"